# Quadratic equation, smallest value of k

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms

What is the smallest value of $k$, for which both roots of the equation $x^2-8kx+16(k^2-k+1)=0$ are real, distinct and have values at least $4$?

**My Try:** I absolutely have no idea how to approach this logically, but I get a feeling $k$ is zero ( I may be wrong ).

*Can someone please tell me more of a logical approach to solve similar problems?*

Comment: I don't know what you mean about "values." For the earlier part, do you know what the discriminant is?

Comment: 'Values' means values of the two roots of the equation.

Comment: You haven't answered to the second, essential, question of @Will Jagy about the discriminant.

Comment: I'm sorry yes I know the discriminant, its coming out to be $64(k-1)$. It has to be position for distinct real roots I know that but what other conditions do I need?

Comment: Remember that a quadratic with $\Delta < 0$ has no real roots.

Comment: I know. I just commented on that.

Comment: @Tanuj Must the quadratic have 2 roots?

Comment: According to the question, yes!

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the function $y=f(x)=x^2-8kx+16(k^2-k+1)$. This represents an upwards facing parabola. Now we will apply the various conditions given.

1. For roots to be real, you need the discriminant to be $\geq 0$.
2. For roots to be distinct, you need the discriminant to be $\neq 0$.
3. For both roots to be $\geq 4$, since the parabola is facing upwards, $f(4) \geq 0$ and the $x-$coordinate of the vertex of the parabola (global min) should lie to the right of $4$.

In your case, comparing with $ax^2+bx+c=0$, the discriminant is
$$b^2-4ac=64k^2-64(k^2-k+1).$$

So the first two conditions imply that
$$64k^2-64(k^2-k+1) >0 \implies k >1.$$

From the third condition, we get
\begin{align*}
f(4) & \geq 0\\
16-32k+16(k^2-k+1 & \geq 0\\
k^2-3k+2 &\geq 0\\
k & \in (-\infty, 1] \cup [2, \infty)
\end{align*}

Now we impose the vertex condition. The vertex is at $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$, so
\begin{align*}
\frac{-b}{2a} &> 4\\
\frac{8k}{2} &> 4\\
k & > 1.
\end{align*}

Combining all these we get
$$k \in [2, \infty).$$

Comment: How did you come up with the final solution? I mean how did you combine all the inequalities?

Comment: @Tanuj the first and the last inequality both want $k>1$, the second inequality says either $k \leq 1$ OR $k \geq 2$. So just ask yourself what is the interval on which we can have all of them satisfied?

Comment: Gotchya! Just take the intersection, right? +1 by the way.

Comment: [+1] I would like to attract your attention on a detail that looks me important. You say $y=x^2-8kx+\cdots$ **is** a parabola ; maybe it should be better to say that it **is the equation** of a parabola.

Answer (score 3):

By completing the square $\;x^2 −8kx+16(k^2 −k+1)=0⟺(x−4k)^2 =16(k−1)\,$. For the latter to have real and distinct roots, the RHS must be strictly positive, thus $\,k \gt 1\,$, and in that case the two real roots are $\,4k \pm 4 \sqrt{k-1}\,$. The condition that the *smaller* root of the two is at least $\,4\,$ then translates to $\,4k - 4 \sqrt{k-1} \ge 4\,$ $\iff$ $k-1 \ge \sqrt{k-1}$ $\iff$ $k \ge 2\,$.